# How to remove escape codes from strings after scraping a website

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

I try to learn data science with python in simplilearn. in matplotlib learning section they do web scraping from [here](https://www.hubertiming.com/results/2018MLK).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url="https://www.hubertiming.com/results/2018MLK" #OPEN LINK
html=urlopen(URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
title = soup.title
print (title)
print(title.text)
links = soup.find_all('a',href=True)
for link in links:
    print (link['href'])
data =[]
allrows=soup.find_all("tr")
for row in allrows:
    row_list = row.find_all("td")
    dataRow=[]
    data_converted = []
    for cell in row_list:
        dataRow.append(cell.text)
    data.append(dataRow)
data=data[4:]
print(data[-2:])
```

And this is the results

```
[['190', '2087', '\r\n\r\n                    LEESHA POSEY\r\n\r\n                ', 'F', '43', 'PORTLAND', 'OR', '1:33:53', '30:17', '\r\n\r\n                    112 of 113\r\n\r\n                ', 'F 40-54', '\r\n\r\n                    36 of 37\r\n\r\n                ', '0:00', '1:33:53'], ['191', '1216', '\r\n\r\n                    ZULMA OCHOA\r\n\r\n                ', 'F', '40', 'GRESHAM', 'OR', '1:43:27', '33:22', '\r\n\r\n                    113 of 113\r\n\r\n                ', 'F 40-54', '\r\n\r\n                    37 of 37\r\n\r\n                ', '0:00', '1:43:27']]
```

how can I get rid the `\r\n\r\n`?? i already use `"replace"` function and it say `"'list' object has no attribute 'replace'"` and also I can not use strip neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having 2D List

###### What are we leveraging:

1. List Comprehension
2. `strip()` method
3. Thats it :)

Use the below code:

```py
text = [['190', '2087', '\r\n\r\n LEESHA POSEY\r\n\r\n ', 'F', '43', 'PORTLAND', 'OR', '1:33:53', '30:17', '\r\n\r\n 112 of 113\r\n\r\n ', 'F 40-54', '\r\n\r\n 36 of 37\r\n\r\n ', '0:00', '1:33:53'], ['191', '1216', '\r\n\r\n ZULMA OCHOA\r\n\r\n ', 'F', '40', 'GRESHAM', 'OR', '1:43:27', '33:22', '\r\n\r\n 113 of 113\r\n\r\n ', 'F 40-54', '\r\n\r\n 37 of 37\r\n\r\n ', '0:00', '1:43:27']]
result = [[j.strip() for j in i] for i in text]
print(result)
```

Output:

```py
[['190', '2087', 'LEESHA POSEY', 'F', '43', 'PORTLAND', 'OR', '1:33:53', '30:17', '112 of 113', 'F 40-54', '36 of 37', '0:00', '1:33:53'], ['191', '1216', 'ZULMA OCHOA', 'F', '40', 'GRESHAM', 'OR', '1:43:27', '33:22', '113 of 113', 'F 40-54', '37 of 37', '0:00', '1:43:27']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this only. convert: `cell.text` to `cell.text.strip()` in your code like below:

```
...
for row in allrows:
    row_list = row.find_all("td")
    dataRow=[]
    data_converted = []
    for cell in row_list:
        dataRow.append(cell.text.strip())
...
```

Answer (score 1):

- This website has well defined table tags. As such, the easiest solution is to use [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html), which will scrape all the tables into a list of dataframes.

  - If there are no table tags in the html, then `.read_html()` will not work.
- Since this reads the tables correctly, there are no extra escape codes to strip or remove, but if that were required for a column of data, something like `df.Name = df.Name.str.strip()` or `df.Name = df.Name.str.replace('\r', '')`, would work.
- This has the benefit of reducing the code to two lines, and the data will be easier to manipulate, analyze, and plot

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.hubertiming.com/results/2018MLK'

# read the tables
df_list = pd.read_html(url)

# in this case the desired dataframe is at index 1
df = df_list[1]

# display(df.head())
   Place   Bib                     Name Gender   Age        City State Chip Time Chip Pace Gender Place Age Group Age Group Place Time to Start Gun Time
0      1  1191             MAX RANDOLPH      M  29.0  WASHINGTON    DC     16:48      5:25      1 of 78   M 21-39         1 of 33          0:08    16:56
1      2  1080  NEED NAME KAISER RUNNER      M  25.0    PORTLAND    OR     17:31      5:39      2 of 78   M 21-39         2 of 33          0:09    17:40
2      3  1275               DAN FRANEK      M  52.0    PORTLAND    OR     18:15      5:53      3 of 78   M 40-54         1 of 27          0:07    18:22
3      4  1223              PAUL TAYLOR      M  54.0    PORTLAND    OR     18:31      5:58      4 of 78   M 40-54         2 of 27          0:07    18:38
4      5  1245              THEO KINMAN      M  22.0         NaN   NaN     19:31      6:17      5 of 78   M 21-39         3 of 33          0:09    19:40

# output the dataframe as an array, and see the values in the last two lists have no escape codes
data = df.to_numpy()
print(data[-2:])
[out]: 
array([[190, 2087, 'LEESHA POSEY', 'F', 43.0, 'PORTLAND', 'OR',
        '1:33:53', '30:17', '112 of 113', 'F 40-54', '36 of 37', '0:00',
        '1:33:53'],
       [191, 1216, 'ZULMA OCHOA', 'F', 40.0, 'GRESHAM', 'OR', '1:43:27',
        '33:22', '113 of 113', 'F 40-54', '37 of 37', '0:00', '1:43:27']],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
text = [['190', '2087', '\r\n\r\n LEESHA POSEY\r\n\r\n ', 'F', '43', 'PORTLAND', 'OR', '1:33:53', '30:17', '\r\n\r\n 112 of 113\r\n\r\n ', 'F 40-54', '\r\n\r\n 36 of 37\r\n\r\n ', '0:00', '1:33:53'], ['191', '1216', '\r\n\r\n ZULMA OCHOA\r\n\r\n ', 'F', '40', 'GRESHAM', 'OR', '1:43:27', '33:22', '\r\n\r\n 113 of 113\r\n\r\n ', 'F 40-54', '\r\n\r\n 37 of 37\r\n\r\n ', '0:00', '1:43:27']]
print(text)
for i in range(len(text)):
    for j in range(len(text[i])):
        text[i][j] = text[i][j].replace('\r\n', '')
print(text)
```

Output:

```
[['190', '2087', '\r\n\r\n LEESHA POSEY\r\n\r\n ', 'F', '43', 'PORTLAND', 'OR', '1:33:53', '30:17', '\r\n\r\n 112 of 113\r\n\r\n ', 'F 40-54', '\r\n\r\n 36 of 37\r\n\r\n ', '0:00', '1:33:53'], ['191', '1216', '\r\n\r\n ZULMA OCHOA\r\n\r\n ', 'F', '40', 'GRESHAM', 'OR', '1:43:27', '33:22', '\r\n\r\n 113 of 113\r\n\r\n ', 'F 40-54', '\r\n\r\n 37 of 37\r\n\r\n ', '0:00', '1:43:27']]
[['190', '2087', ' LEESHA POSEY ', 'F', '43', 'PORTLAND', 'OR', '1:33:53', '30:17', ' 112 of 113 ', 'F 40-54', ' 36 of 37 ', '0:00', '1:33:53'], ['191', '1216', ' ZULMA OCHOA ', 'F', '40', 'GRESHAM', 'OR', '1:43:27', '33:22', ' 113 of 113 ', 'F 40-54', ' 37 of 37 ', '0:00', '1:43:27']]
```